# Is there a reason the site-local Meta privileges page is blank?

Tags: support, status-completed, meta, help-center, privileges

The main, network-wide Meta has a [privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/) that lists the privileges for that Meta, but it looks like none of the local sites have that information on their privileges page (e.g., [Christianity's privileges page](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/); I checked Writers and Stack Overflow as well and they also lack the information provided on Meta Stack Exchange).

Is this a bug, a misfeature, or is the problem on my end somehow?

Comment: It's empty for me too. Probably a bug on their end.

Comment: Mine's empty as well. My understanding is that privs on meta match privs on main, so it not necessary to really have it. On MSE, however, it is a full site of its own with rep and everything, so it makes sense that it is there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's NOT a bug.  You can actually earn reputation points on the main META site.  You can't do that on this META.  ON all other META sites, the points shown are those from the main site.  On the main META site, the reputation is independent.  Since you don't earn rep on the other META sites, there's no need to explain privileges.  Your Privileges on this META are exactly the same as those on the parent site - Christianity.SE.  You'd probably need an SE developer to answer for sure, so maybe this would be better asked there.

Comment: Oh, look!  [My guess was good!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67638/meta-stackexchange-com-privileges-doesnt-exist)

Comment: @DavidStratton Your search skills are impressive. I looked (admittedly briefly) for reputation limits on Metas at Meta.SE, but only found arguments about adding rep. requirements distinct from the main sites. I *suspected* that the fact that rep. isn't earned on local Metas was involved, but I wanted confirmation that posting an answer on Meta had a 1 reputation requirement (because of a suggestion I made on Writers about enabling new uses to chat about NaNoWriMo).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More than anything, this was an oversight on our end.

As David Startton surmised, child-meta sites (sites that have an attached parent Q&Q site - such as this meta site, meta Stack Overflow, meta Writers and so on - which excludes Meta Stack Exchange, as it doesn't have a parent Q&A site) do not have their own privileges, given that both reputation and privileges of each user on it are inherited from the parent site.

As such, all existing links to the privileges pages point to the privileges pages of the *parent* site.

However, we were not accounting for direct access to these pages via the URL - people actually typing in the address of the page on a child-meta.

I have made some changes on our end - when trying to go to the page on a child-meta, we will be redirecting to the parent site pages.

This will be deployed in the next build (rev 2014.10.7.1915)